# SVN Update Postpone --> How to resolve?

Tags: svn

When I did `svn update` and SVN asked me about a few differences, I told it to postpone them.

Now I would like to resolve them, but `svn update` just tells me "up to date", even though `svn diff` shows me the differences.

How do I make `svn update` ask me about the conflicts again?

Comment: What about `svn status`? `svn update` shouldn't output anything as long as nothing added to the central repository

Comment: what does `svn status` show? Anything about changelists?

Comment: @zerkms: `svn status` shows lots of files with `?` in the front, as well as some `M` and `C` files (not sure what they mean).

Comment: I have the same problem as topic starter, all of my files have status M. And they don't update even when I use 'svn up --force' command. 'svn resolve' also doesn't help because as I understand the files are not conflicted (C). How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`svn update` won't ask about the conflicts again because it has dealt with them.

As for the meaning of `svn status`, The `?` files are not managed by SVN, the `M` ones have been modified, and the `C` ones are the conflicted ones that you postponed. If you open one of the `C` files, and look through it you will see markers in your code showing you where the conflicts are. You need to edit each one of these, fix the conflicts and remove the markers. And then you need to run `svn resolve` to tell SVN that things are OK. Make sure to use the `--help` option and Google to learn how `svn resolve` works before you run it.

If you don't do all of this, `svn commit` will no longer work.

`svn status` is really important to understand, because svn diff only shows things that happened locally after `svn update`. But, `svn status -u` gives an overview after querying the repository. Most importantly, it clearly identifies files with conflicts (`C` in column 1) which you have to open in an editor and check manually.

Comment: Correction: svn status will only go to the repository if you specify '-u', otherwise it only looks at the files in the .svn directories

Comment: And this isn't entirely correct. There are two commands: `svn resolve` and `svn resolved`. They're different. `svn resolved` is what you meant to suggest, as it tells subversion that "things are OK". What the original poster wants is `svn resolve`, which starts up the conflict resolution process again, prompting for changes, offering to launch editors, etc.

Answer (score 9):

When you run `svn commit`, you will have a list of the files in conflict.
You can then resolve the conflicts by issuing commands such as :

```
svn resolve --accept=theirs-full '/path/to/the/file'
```

Type `svn resolve --help` for a list of the available conflict resolution modes.

Answer (score 1):

After postpone, you have to run svn resolve for each file in conflict.

If you want to see the conflicts, you can run :

```
svn resolve /path/to/file
```

select "m" for fusion

For each conflict, you see both versions.
You can choose to use your version, theirs, a mix (your then theirs, their then yours) or to edit one or both version.

Exemple :

```
    Conflicting section found during merge:
        (1) their version (à la ligne 88)    |(2) your version (à la ligne 77)  
        -------------------------------------+----------------------------------
        text = new_box(name, column, option) |  text = new_box(name, column) 
        -------------------------------------+----------------------------------

        Select: (1) use their version, (2) use your version,
                (12) their version first, then yours,
                (21) your version first, then theirs,
                (e1) edit their version and use the result,
                (e2) edit your version and use the result,
                (eb) edit both versions and use the result,
                (p) postpone this conflicting section leaving conflict markers,
                (a) abort file merge and return to main menu: 2
```

then you choose "r" to mark the conflict resolved.